# How to build local web proxy without configuring the browsers

Tags: installation, webproxy

How does Netnanny or k9 Web Protection setup web proxy without configuring the browsers?
How can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using WinSock directly, or at the [NDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification) or hardware driver level, and
then filter at those levels, just like any firewalls soft does. [NDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Driver_Interface_Specification) being the easy way.

Download this ISO image: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=36a2630f-5d56-43b5-b996-7633f2ec14ff
it has bunch of samples and tools to help you build what you want. 
After you mount or burn it on CD and install it go to this folder: 
`c:\WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\network\ndis\`

Comment: how hard is to write all windows OP's application based on NDIS ?

Comment: Thanks for the replays, few question , im c++ programmer manly on linux , windows is new thing for me. 1. does programming once will run on all windows OP's? currently as i see it its the best solution 
what i whant to do is basic thing like netnanny and k9 doing to filter web requests

Comment: ok , now i found this : Layered Service Provider. can it be the thing im looking for .. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_service_provider

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is a transparent proxy that support WCCP.

Take a look at [squid-cache FAQ page](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/InterceptionProxy)

And the Wikipedia entry for [WCCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Cache_Communication_Protocol)

With that setup you just need to do some firewall configuration and all your web traffic will be handled by the transparent proxy. And no setup will be needed on your browser.

Answer (score 1):

netnanny is not a proxy. It is tied to the host machine and browser (and possibly other applications as well. It then filters all incoming and outgoing "content" from the machine/application.

Essentially Netnanny is a content-control system as against destination-control system (proxy).

Easiest way to divert all traffic to a certain site to some other address is by changing hosts file on local host

Comment: when i installed net nanny , i checked if they attached some BHO or some plug in to FF , and i didn't found any what i did saw they have some component as service .

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the explanation here: http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp

This is how Fiddler2 achieves inserting a proxy in between most apps and the internet without modifying the apps (although lots of explanation of how-to failing the default setup).  This does not answer how NetNanny/K9 etc work though, as noted above they do a little more and may be a little more intrusive.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you search for [BrowserHelperObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). These little gizmos capture ALL browser communication, and as such can either remote ads from the HTML (good gizmo), or redirect every second click to a spam site (bad gizmo), or just capture every URL you type and send it home like all the WebToolBars do.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is route all outgoing http(s) requests from your lan through a reverse proxy (like [squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)).  This is the setup for a [transparent web proxy](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/TransparentProxy.html).

There are different ways to do this, although I've only ever set it up [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/) and Linux; and using [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as the reverse proxy.

At a high level you have a firewall with rules to send all externally bound http traffic to a local squid server.  The [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) server is configured to:

- accept all http requests
- forward the requests on to the real external hosts
- cache the reply
- forward the reply back to the requestor on the local lan

You can then add more granular rules in [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) to control access to websites, filter content, etc.

I pretty sure you can also get this functionality in different networking gear.  I bet F5 has some products that do some or all of what I described, and probably Cisco as well.  There is probably other proxies out there besides [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) that you can use too.

PS.  I have no idea if this is how K9 Web Protection or NetNanny works.

Answer (score 0):

Squid could provide an intercept proxy for HTTP and HTTPs ports, without configuring the browsers and it also supports WCCP.